# Show x and y labels in each facet subplot in Altair

Tags: python, altair

I refer to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56537031/4107770):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
).facet(
    facet='species:N',
    columns=2
)
```

This yields a plot with 3 subplots, where the x and y axes are shared. I want that every subplot has its own x and y label (even if this is repeated). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using the [`resolve_axis`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html#altair.Chart.resolve_axis) method, discussed in [Scale and Guide Resolution](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris()

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=180,
    height=180
).facet(
    facet='species:N',
    columns=2
).resolve_axis(
    x='independent',
    y='independent',
)
```

[image]